# Istio-ingress behind Google cloud Layer 7 load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio, google-cloud-load-balancer

Problem I am facing is that my istio-ingressgateway is working perfectly file at network layer load balancer(L4 loadbalancer or TCP load balancer) but when i connect istio-ingressgateway to Layer7 load balancer by attaching nodePort at backend service.after that http to https redirection not working properly its always give Response code 301  even when i request using https protocol.

Comment: Do you use GKE? or a custom K8S deployment?

Comment: I am using GKE. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Do you use the istio Add-on? Or do you install Istio by yourself ?

Comment: i installed it by my self @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Just to understand well. You have an ingress-gateway define by Istio. This gateway has spawn an TCP load balancer on GCP. You have expose a service as NodePort, define an istio gateway and an istio virtual service and you can reach your service through the TCP load balancer. Now, you want to create an HTTP loadbalancer, to define the instance group as backend and reach it in HTTP and HTTPS. Am I correct? The backend is healthy but the response is 301. How do you test your HTTP loadbalancer ? Curl? Via Browser?

Comment: Yeah you are right we connect GKE instances as a backend of loadbalancer and its health check is perfectly fine. I tested it by both way curl and browser too.

Comment: How did you get your backend port? Is it in HTTP or HTTPS ?

Comment: I connected it with HTTP NodePort

Comment: I even tried it with HTTPS port  but LB is not connected with it. and LoadBalancer give 502 @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 1):

I successfully configured the same architecture. Here the step to reproduce:

- Deploy a GKE cluster. Either with Istio, or with istio installed afterward.
- Get the Istio-ingressgateway nodeport for http:

```
kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].port}'
```

- Create a Global Loadbalancer
- Create a backend service and select your cluster InstanceGroup.
- Set the istio-ingressgateway nodeport as port
- Create an health check, on the same nodeport value, in TCP mode
- Configure your URL path
- Validate and wait 5-10 minutes for letting the time to the health check to validate your configuration and to route the traffic

Now, you can reach your K8S cluster, through the Istio Nodeport with the global load balancer. Deploy a service on Istio, you could reach it through the Global Loadbalancer.

Comment: did you try https redirection with L7 load balancer ? Because i am able to connect application with L7 load balancer but HTTPS redirection not working properly

Comment: @gguillaume-blaquiere why the health check has to be in TCP mode? Can't we use a HTTP health check? I tried your approach with a HTTP health check that checks ```/healthz/ready``` path of istio-ingressgateway, health check passes but app returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on GitHub, Please check: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/17980